# Idea for IOS app to work with Filemaker. Possible?

Tags: filemaker

I created a database using filemaker and long story short the database is for Janitors. All they have to do is choose yes or no from a drop down list or choose 1 2 3 for the type of task that is done. Now here is what my boss's idea is. He wants to make QR(or bardcodes, not sure which works) codes for each restroom in the school. They will just be a number. Now there will be 3 other QR codes with options 1 2 3 (cleaned, restocked, deep clean). His idea is to make an app that reads the QR codes and perform a find and input the restroom number. Now after its in the correct restroom they scan the other QR code and it inputs what type of task was done depending on the one that was scanned.

Here it is in steps:

1.Scan the code that is the restroom number(will open FM then add a new record in filemaker with the restroom number)

2.Scan the other code which will be the type of restroom and set the field for the type of task done.

Is this idea possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, though I would adjust your approach and add some detail.

**Searching for room by barcode**

I think this section of the idea is a good one. You could do this with either qr codes or a different barcode type. Here's an article by Greg Lane that talks about [Using Barcodes with FileMaker Go](http://www.skeletonkey.com/using-barcodes-with-filemaker-go/) (Full disclosure: I work for Skeleton Key).

What you would want to do is to write a script that does the following when clicking on a "Find Room" button or some other trigger:

- Enter's find mode
- Goes to a layout that has the `Room Number` field that holds the room numbers that you'd be searching through
- Uses the `Insert from Device`

  - Specify that it's a barcode you want to scan and give it the type you want to scan
  - Use your `Room Number` field as the target field (This will tell FileMaker to translate what was scanned into text and put it into that text field)
- Perform Find

This is a super simplified outline of the script you'd want to write. When you actually write it you would also want to add in error capturing and any other changes to make it fit your need.

**Barcode Generation**

The portion that you need to add into your plan is how you're going to generate and print the barcodes you're going to use. If you already have a way of printing barcodes than this is a moot point, but if you don't you can print them directly from the Room records in your FileMaker database.

Todd Geist wrote a nice blog on [Printing Barcodes with FileMaker](https://www.geistinteractive.com/2014/06/02/printing-barcodes-filemaker/) that will be helpful. Also, if you have access to this year's (2014) DevCon videos you could watch the session for Super Charging your Workflows with Barcodes by Greg Lane.

**Scanning a barcode for Task**

This is the one I would change. Searching for a room number with a barcode is a good idea because:

- The barcode to scan lives in a specific place (at each room door)
- It would be "more difficult" to manually search for the room number than it would to scan a barcode and let the app do the search

In the case of a task to be completed though, I think the barcode scanning to mark the task that was done will actually be more cumbersome.

First, you would need to have the barcodes for each somewhere that the user could scan it to mark the specific task complete. This means your user needs to either carry the barcodes with them or you need to post them at each room location. Neither is convenient.

Second, if there are only 3 tasks they could complete and the user is already on the room record from scanning the room number barcode, then it would be easier for both them and you as the developer to put 3 buttons on the layout for a room that correspond to each task they could complete.

Adding in barcode scanning for completing a task would be adding in an extra layer of complication that isn't really needed.

**Overall flow**

In the end, I think your idea is a good one and one that I've programmed in one form or the other many many times. I think the overall flow you want (which is very close to what you already had) is:

- Print out the barcodes for the rooms and place the codes at the door of each room
- Build a "Scan to find room" structure into your application
- Once the user find's the room, have a button for each task they could complete

Hope this helps!

Comment: So there is no need to create an extra app for this, correct? All of this can be done within filemaker.

Comment: That's correct. FileMaker can do all parts of what you're wanting to do. It will take some work, research, and hardware (you'll need an iOS device that can use FileMaker Go 13 for each janitor) but it can definitely be done.